# Kendo UI JSP tag library in JSF

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, kendo-ui

Is it possible to insert the Kendo UI JSP tag library (and in general all JSP tag library) in a JSF file? If yes, how?

In particular, I use NetBeans, I added the Kendo UI library in my project, but I can't understand how to integrate the tags into my jsf files.

Answer (score 1):

JSP is **deprecated** since JSF2 (dec 2009) and succeeded by [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info). JSP tag libraries don't work in Facelets at all. You basically need a Facelets compatible tag library, such as PrimeFaces, RichFaces, ICEfaces, OpenFaces, Tomahawk, OmniFaces, etc.

You can keep using legacy JSP in JSF2 the same way as you would do for JSF 1.x, but you won't be able to benefit new JSF2 tags/features such as `<f:ajax>`, `<h:head>`, `<h:outputScript>`, etc, let alone utilize templating via Facelets `<ui:xxx>` tags.

Kendo UI is as to the available Java based taglibs apparently still hanging in ancient J2EE era and has still to catch up the new Java EE era.